# Turn off instant validation when losing focus

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo as the client framework. I have a `ValidationTextBox` call `txtName` as below screen:

[image]

In `txtName`, `required` is set:

```
 required="true"
```

If I lose focus and leave `txtName` empty (tab, or click to another textbox), the validation execute immediately by highlighting by red.

My question: Is there anyway that we turn off this, and just only do validation when I click on `Save` button. I tried set:

```
 intermediateChanges="false"
```

but no luck. The same situation with `StartDate` and `EndDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a setting that you can just set.  But you can monkey patch the `ValidationTextBox` to get what you need.

```
ValidationTextBox.prototype._setValueAttr = function() {
  //this.inherited(arguments);
  //this.validate(this.focused); Do not validate
  TextBox.prototype._setValueAttr.apply(this, arguments);
};

ValidationTextBox.prototype._refreshState = function(){
  TextBox.prototype._refreshState.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/Y7Eqn/

Comment: Thanks, it actually works with mouse click but does not work with Tab key

Comment: Looks like _refreshState needs to be patched as well