# class based vs functional jQuery approach ( custom textinput with validation )

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypal-inheritance

What is the best way to create custom TextInput with custom logic for validation using javacript.

Is prototypal inheritance more suitable or Shall I use simple jQuery for validation?

This is not about simple validation, I want to do some complex operations?

Please guide me what is the best approach. I want to have separation of concerns too.

Comment: It might be useful to tell us what kind of validation? Email validation? Checking against a database?

Answer (score 0):

```
in html5 you can simple write it as  input type="text" required="required" id="tip">
```

or in jquery

```
var tt=$("#tip").val();
if(tt=="")
{
 alert('please fill value');
}
```

Comment: I am not talking about basic validation, I am talking about some complex validation using regular expressions. Of course in Html5 we have some support, button I want to know the best approach to follow.

Comment: check the jquery above

Comment: thanks, but do you have an idea of prototypal inheritance, I have to use it not plain jquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979144/turn-off-instant-validation-when-losing-focus

Answer (score 0):

In fact the thing you may want to check is [jquery validation engine](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/)